# i want to get the max(HA) and max(Total) of grouped by 'subject' for all students for the given table

Tags: mysql, sql

**i want to get the max(HA) and max(Total) of grouped by 'subject' for all students
for the given table**

```
Date        Sem   Section   Subject    USN    Name     Status     HA   Total
-----------|------|----------------------------------------------------------------
2013-11-11    1      A         c       01   Akshay    present      1    2
2013-11-11    1      A         c       02   David     absent       1    2
2013-11-11    1      A        .net     01   Akshay    absent       1    2
2013-11-11    1      A        .net     02   David     present      2    2
2013-11-12    1      A         c       01   Akshay    absent       0    1
2013-11-12    1      A         c       02   David     present      1    1
2013-11-12    1      A        .net     01   Akshay    present      1    1
2013-11-12    1      A        .net     02   David     present      1    1


REsult should be:

Sem   Section   Subject   USN    Name     HA   Total
-----|--------|---------|------|--------|-----|------
1        A       c        01    Akshay    1      2
1        A       c        02    David     1      2
1        A     .net       01    Akshay    1      2
1        A     .net       02    David     2      2
```

Pls.. help...

Comment: which `RDBMS` are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  select sem,section,subject,usn, Name, max(HA), MAX(total)
    from table
    group by sem, section, subject, usn, naam
```